# Google service Json Error in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, google-play-services

Please help me. I am getting this error again and again. Even I collect a google-service.json file from Firebase and paste it in root. but still some error are ocuring. Please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are not alone
copy and pate your file to:

> project-root\platforms\android\google-services.json

or

> project-root\platforms\android\app\google-services.json

or

> project-root\platforms\android\app\src\debug\google-services.json